# jquery doesn't see new elements

Tags: jquery, dom, refresh

I am new to JQuery, so bear with me :).

I have a simple problem:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $("#instrument").change(function() {
         $("#tunings").html("<select id=\"TuningSelector>\"[..]</div>");
     });

     $("#TuningSelector").change(function() {
         DoSomethingWithTheValue();
      }); 

 });
```

Problem is: When instrument has changed, the script doesn't respond anymore to TuningSelector changes. Like JQuery doesn't see the new TuningSelector element...

Do I need to call a refresh on JQuery or so? So that it sees the refreshed DOM?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Generally you want to use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on) so that it applies the handler to new elements matching the selector and delegate to a higher element in the DOM.

```
$('body').on( 'change', '#control', function() {
    DoSomething();
});
```

Comment: .live("change") won't be implemented till jQuery 1.4 http://docs.jquery.com/JQuery_1.4_Roadmap#Events

Comment: @Sam - thanks for pointing that out.  I hadn't used it with a select as yet and didn't realize that wasn't in the supported list.  My answer has been updated to reflect this.

Comment: for anyone reading this, .live() is not deprecated in favor of .on()

Comment: You need to add a Semicolon (;) at the end instead of colon

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery events if you want the event to apply to new elements you would use the [.live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) method, however jQuery 1.3 doesn't support blur, focus, mouseenter, mouseleave, change, submit events as live events. (change, submit, and blur/focus are on the [roadmap](http://docs.jquery.com/JQuery_1.4_Roadmap#Events) for jQuery 1.4)

As an alternative you could use the [liveQuery](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery) plugin.