# How to get form input inside ModalBox with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am developing my website using jQuery. For the Private Messaging feature, what I had right now is showing a ModalBox (dialog box). So, whenever user wanna check message, they will be displayed with a dialog box with the inbox shown. Now, inside that ModalBox, I have a "Compose" section where users can send message. My question is, when user submits the form, how we could retrieve those inputs without having to actually submit it? Because, I have tried it..., that when I do the `submit()`, it closed the ModalBox.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you confirm these assumptions:
It is a webpage
By modal box you mean floating div which appears above the background
If these are both correct, your submit is posting back the entire page, refreshing it which redraws it anew without your popup. A way around this would be to consider a javascript postback using Ajax/XHR

Comment: Hi, your assumptions are correct. Well, I did use Ajax on the button and create an event for it. But then, when I use val() on the input (selector), it returned undefined.

Comment: Just a note, I don't think I mentioned this. This form are not prepared on the php or html. It is created "on the fly" using Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, see [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax)

In case you're not familiar with AJAX, basically it allows you to send a request to the server (in this case, your submitted data), process the data on the server, and then receive any return back from your request, all without reloading the entire page.

This should alleviate the issue of the modal box closing (the page reloading upon submit, really.)

[edit]

See [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815074/jquery-doesnt-see-new-elements) from here at StackOverflow on using the live event handler. This should take care of the issue of not getting the value from newly created DOM elements.

[/edit]

Comment: Hey, I do use a lot of Ajax in developing my current website. I am still learning jQuery. Just a note, I don't think I mentioned this. This form are not prepared on the php or html. It is created "on the fly" using Ajax.

Comment: Take a look at the edited answer. It has a link on handling on-the-fly created DOM elements. This should solve your problem of the 'undefined' val() hopefully.