# jQuery make loaded file part of DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've loaded file in div

```
$("#div").load("file.txt");
```

That file has html images .
I want to access them by $('#div>img') (or other selectors), but nothing happens. If they were in page initially, there are no problems.

How can you access loaded content by jQuery as part of the usual page?

Comment: can you provide a sample of what's inside file.txt?

Comment: Are you trying to access them immediately, or are you actually waiting for the load to complete (callback)?

Comment: Are you sure you accessing them *after* file has been loaded and HTML got inserted into DOM?

Comment: <img src='images/jp.gif' />  .live solved the problem. it was after ful loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [jquery doesn't see new elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815074/jquery-doesnt-see-new-elements) for one possible problem you might be having. Use the `change` method to wait until they enter the DOM. e.g.

```
$("#div").load("file.txt");

$('#div>img').change(function(){
  var images = $('#div>img');
  // Do something...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#div").load("file.txt");
$("#div > img")...  // file.txt hasn't finished loading yet
```

Will probably not work, since loading the file happens asynchronously and takes some time, and the content is simply not there yet when you try to access it. For this reason, you can specify a callback that is guaranteed to run *after* the `load()` has finished:

```
$("#div").load("file.txt", function () {
    // file.txt has finished loading, this should work:
    $("#div > img")...
});
```

Comment: Ah! Good thought...why didn't I think of that!

Answer (score 1):

The content loaded (supposedly through Ajax) is rendered as a text string. It's up to you to load it into the DOM using .innerHTML and such. In jQuery you can use `.html()` to load the content inside the DOM and then you're going to be able to access it through standard jQuery DOM selectors.

Comment: it is walkaround, but point is in using dynamical loading. file is big, should be loaded only when neded

Comment: jQuery should interpret the loaded content as HTML, there shouldn't be a need for doing anything else manually. http://api.jquery.com/load/