# How to select second table using jquery

Tags: jquery, selector

Hi there i would like to select forexample second table in html document. I was trying to do so by `table:nth-child(2) or table:eq(1)` but doesnt work. I will appreciate your answers :)

Comment: `$("#container").find(selector).html();` and selector is parsed from xml document. Maybe there is a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the eq filter

```
$('table:eq(1)')
```

More on this topic in the doc http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/.
Remember always the $(document).ready(... call at the beginning of your definition.

Comment: second table would be `:eq(1)` index starts at 0

Comment: @MarcelGentSimonis It's fixed: sorry I'm typing on my phone with some little errors..

Comment: oukey no problem. these should work maybe there's another problem

Comment: @MarcelGentSimonis is your script correctly loaded? is the event which execute your code triggered? there are errors in the JavaScript error console of the browser? Have you tried printing something with window.alert()?

Comment: im am using cross domain query using yql and loading results in #container div which is hidden after this im trying to select second table from within div #container. in console there are errors like some pictures were not found code 404 and thats all. But if im trying to select some div within #container it works but second table doesnt.

Comment: all your answers works i have problem somewhere else sry for disturbing you from sundays morning caffee :)

Comment: @MarcelGentSimonis no problem. take a look at this other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815074/jquery-doesnt-see-new-elements

Answer (score 2):

This should also work selecting all the tables and then finding the right one using [] gives access to the js object and then you convert the js object back to a jQ object.

```
$($("table")[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have also suggested:

```
$('table:nth-child(2)')
```

However if that isn't working, perhaps:

```
$('table').first().next('table')
```

Comment: `next()` selects the  next element in the DOM, it doesn't search for the next table, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I think `table.eq(1)` should `$('table').eq(1)`. **[See here](http://jsfiddle.net/GzRtd/2/)**.

But, if your `table` is a variable then it should be a jQuery object. For example:

```
var table = $('table'); // will returned all existing tables of document (jQuery object)
table.eq(1);
```

will work just fine. **[See here](http://jsfiddle.net/GzRtd/3/)**.